# Create new verison of docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have built a new docker image using the below command

`docker build . -t <username>/<imagename>:<tag>`

and pushed it to docker hub. I can see it fine in repo. When I tried to change a file in it and built a new version of image using same docker build, it is getting as a complete new image (when pushed to docker hub repo).

Can you please suggest what is the right way to create a new version of docker image ?

Thanks
Sri.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Docker-hub keeps the version of your images. For your own tracking it is best practice that while giving image name and tag; you can include the git commit sha so one can look back and verify.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am able to do it now..  I have given a different name(by mistake) while tagging new version so that is going as a new image into repo.

Thanks for those who has taken a look.